# Is there a way to check for an attribute of a script when using script_loader_tag?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

The block of code adds the attribute `async` to a array of Javascript files.

Is there a way to check if the files have already have the attribute assigned and if yes, to skip it?

```
function async_scripts( $tag, $handler, $src ) {
    
    /**
     * An array of JavaScripts files. The value should be the filename.
     */
    $scripts = array(
        'script_one.js',
        'script_two.js'
    );
    
    /**
     * Loop through each file in the $scripts array and add an async option.
     */
    foreach ( $scripts as $script ) {

        if ( true == strpos( $tag, $script ) )
        return str_replace( ' src', ' async src', $tag );
    }

    return $tag;

}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'async_scripts', 10, 3 );
```

I tried looping through `global $wp_scripts` however it doesn't appear to work with `script_loader_tag`

```
foreach( $wp_scripts->registered as $script ) {
            if ( ! empty( $script->extra['async'] ) && $script->extra['async'] === true ) {
                return $tag;
            }
```

Comment: How about checking for `true == strpos( $tag, $script ) && ! preg_match( '/ async\b/', $tag )` (or use `preg_match( '/<script( .+)? async\b.*?>/', $tag )`) instead of just `true == strpos( $tag, $script )` ..? But then, that's a generic PHP matter..

Comment: @SallyCJ - I considered that however it's not matching for some odd reason. It matches other attributes. The theme appears to be adding the async attribute with `wp_script_add_data( 'theme-navigation', 'async', true );`

Comment: `wp_script_add_data()` itself will not add the `async` attribute, so the theme is likely adding that attribute manually (which you'll have to find out how - what function, hook, file, etc.). But even so, if the simple `preg_match()` failed, then maybe it didn't actually fail, but it never ran for the `theme-navigation` script. So try using a lower priority, i.e. a higher number as the 3rd parameter for `add_filter()`, e.g. 20 as in `add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'async_scripts', 20, 3 )`.

Comment: (If lowering the priority doesn't work, you can try my new regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/uoUD5o/1)..)